# Handle repetitive argument check that throws an exception

Tags: java, exception

So I came across a problem with my code: I have ~30 classes which inherit from a superclass called "Minigame".
Each class has similar parameters, but also per-class parameters, depending on the type of the minigame.
Some of the parameters can be illegal (for example, a negative radius), and in a case like this, I want to throw my MinigameConfigurationException.

The problem is that the code seems too repetitive and I couldn't find a better way to handle it.
This is the current code:

```
    @Override
public void setupMinigameParameters() {
    super.setupMinigameParameters();

    YamlConfiguration config = super.getGame().getMain().getFileManager().getConfig(Parameters.MINIGAMES_DIR() + super.getMinigameName()).getConfig();

    if(config.contains("parameters.radius")) radius = config.getInt("parameters.radius");
    if(config.contains("parameters.maximum_amount_of_animals")) maximum_amount_of_animals = config.getInt("parameters.maximum_amount_of_animals");
    if(config.contains("parameters.minimum_amount_of_animals")) minimum_amount_of_animals = config.getInt("parameters.minimum_amount_of_animals");
    if(config.contains("parameters.negative_animals_percentage")) negative_animals_percentage = config.getInt("parameters.negative_animals_percentage");
    if(config.contains("parameters.negative_points_loss_percentage")) negative_points_loss_percentage = config.getInt("parameters.negative_points_loss_percentage");
    if(config.contains("parameters.animals") && config.isConfigurationSection("parameters.animals")) {
        for(String s : config.getConfigurationSection("parameters.animals").getKeys(false))
            animal_types.put(EntityType.valueOf(s), config.getInt("parameters.animals." + s));
    } else {
        animal_types.put(EntityType.CHICKEN, 1);
        animal_types.put(EntityType.PIG, 3);
        animal_types.put(EntityType.COW, 5);
    }

    try {
        handleExceptions();
    } catch(MinigameConfigurationException e) {
        stopMinigame();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.animals = new HashMap<>();
}
```

and then the handleExceptions() method is this one:

```
    public void handleExceptions() throws MinigameConfigurationException {
    if(radius <= 0)
        throw new MinigameConfigurationException(MinigameConfigurationException.MinigameConfigurationExceptionType.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, radius + "", "> 0");
    if(maximum_amount_of_animals < 0)
        throw new MinigameConfigurationException(MinigameConfigurationException.MinigameConfigurationExceptionType.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, maximum_amount_of_animals + "", "> 0");
    if(minimum_amount_of_animals < 0)
        throw new MinigameConfigurationException(MinigameConfigurationException.MinigameConfigurationExceptionType.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, minimum_amount_of_animals + "", "> 0");
    if(negative_animals_percentage <= 0)
        throw new MinigameConfigurationException(MinigameConfigurationException.MinigameConfigurationExceptionType.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, negative_animals_percentage + "", "=> 0 & <= 100");
    if(negative_points_loss_percentage <= 0)
        throw new MinigameConfigurationException(MinigameConfigurationException.MinigameConfigurationExceptionType.ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT, negative_points_loss_percentage + "", "=> 0 & <= 100");
}
```

It feels like bad code, but on the other hand, I couldn't find a different solution.

- By the way, this code is from one class, I need to do it in 30 other classes, that's why it's too repetitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I see that you want to validate the data comes from "outside", so in this case [Java Bean Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation) lib can be helpful. You can use annotations to specify range of each field and in one method invoke validation executor which checks it. If object contains some illegal state you can pass value and message to the exception.